# Pad spacer and mechanical disc brakes

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, mechanical

My bike, a Trek, has Tektro mechanical disc brakes. Do I need to insert a pad spacer when the wheel is removed to prevent the brake from locking if the lever is accidentally moved?

Answer (score 9):

No, mechanical disc brakes do not auto-compensate for pad wear like hydraulic brakes do. They will fully retract every time, pads or no pads.